# target="_blank" not working with download attribute

Tags: html, angular, download, anchor, minio

I am using  as below:

`<a [href]="pdfSrc" target="_blank" download="pdfName">Download</a>`

whereas pdfSrc is coming from API response and it is a minio link.
If I use sample .pdf file target="_blank" is opening, but when I use minio link it is opening the pdf in the current tab.

I want to open minio link pdf in a new tab, I am unable to do it with minio link.

Comment: can you share sample `minio` link here

Comment: @jitender It is with VPN so you cannot connect with it

Comment: If anybody can help me with any other method to download this minio link pdf directly or by opening it in new tab

Comment: It's not to connect with it, it's just to see how your URL looks. It would be helpful if you could provide a sample URL for your minio link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a method in component to [open pdf in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512485/5621827)  somthing like

```
pdfSrc='http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf';

 download(){
    var redirectWindow = window.open(this.pdfSrc, '_blank');
    redirectWindow.location;
 }
```

And then call this method on href click

```
<a (click)="download()" download="pdfName">Download</a>
```

[Stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9atwm6)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using razor helper functions you can code it this way also:

<a href="@Url.Content("pdfName")" target="_blank"</a>